# What is wrong with my custom logistic regression implementation?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to reflect almost the same results as sklearn would give but I am not getting good results. The values of intercepts from my custom implementation and sklearn's implementation have a difference of 5, so I am trying to reduce this value here as much as possible as I can.

My code with sklearn is below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=50000, n_features=15, n_informative=10, n_redundant=5,
                           n_classes=2, weights=[0.7], class_sep=0.7, random_state=15)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=15)
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(eta0=0.0001, alpha=0.0001, loss='log', random_state=15, penalty='l2', tol=1e-3, verbose=2, learning_rate='constant')

clf.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train) # fitting our model

print(clf.coef_, clf.coef_.shape, clf.intercept_)
```

This results in

```
(array([[-0.42336692,  0.18547565, -0.14859036,  0.34144407, -0.2081867 ,
          0.56016579, -0.45242483, -0.09408813,  0.2092732 ,  0.18084126,
          0.19705191,  0.00421916, -0.0796037 ,  0.33852802,  0.02266721]]),
 (1, 15),
 array([-0.8531383]))
```

My custom implementation

```
def initialize_weights(dim):
    ''' In this function, we will initialize our weights and bias'''
    #initialize the weights to zeros array of (dim,1) dimensions
    #you use zeros_like function to initialize zero
    #initialize bias to zero
    w = np.zeros_like(dim)
    b = 0

    return w,b

def sigmoid(z):
    ''' In this function, we will return sigmoid of z'''
    # compute sigmoid(z) and return
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def logloss(y_true,y_pred):
    
    '''In this function, we will compute log loss '''
    loss = 0
    A = list(zip(y_true, y_pred))
    for y, y_score in A:
        loss += (-1/len(A))*(y*np.log10(y_score) + (1-y) * np.log10(1-y_score))
    return loss

def gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
    '''In this function, we will compute the gardient w.r.to w '''
    z = np.dot(w, x) + b
    dw = x*(y - sigmoid(z)) - ((1/alpha)*(1/N) * w)
    return dw

def gradient_db(x,y,w,b):
    z = np.dot(w, x) + b
    db = y - sigmoid(z)

    return DB

def train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0, tol=1e-3):
    ''' In this function, we will implement logistic regression'''
    #Here eta0 is learning rate
    #implement the code as follows
    # initalize the weights (call the initialize_weights(X_train[0]) function)
    w, b = initialize_weights(X_train[0])
    # for every epoch
    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # for every data point(X_train,y_train)
        for x, y in zip(X_train, y_train):
             #compute gradient w.r.to w (call the gradient_dw() function)
            dw = gradient_dw(x, y, w, b, alpha, len(X_train))
            #compute gradient w.r.to b (call the gradient_db() function)
            db = gradient_db(x, y, w, b)
            #update w, b
            w = w + eta0 * dw
            b = b + eta0 * db
        
        # predict the output of x_train[for all data points in X_train] using w,b
        y_pred = [sigmoid(np.dot(w, x)) for x in X_train]
        #compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)
        train_loss.append(logloss(y_train, y_pred))
        # store all the train loss values in a list
        # predict the output of x_test[for all data points in X_test] using w,b
        y_pred_test = [sigmoid(np.dot(w, x)) for x in X_test]
        print(f"EPOCH: {epoch} Train Loss: {logloss(y_train, y_pred)} Test Loss: {logloss(y_test, y_pred_test)}")
        #compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)
        test_loss.append(logloss(y_test, y_pred_test))
        
        # you can also compare previous loss and current loss if the loss is not updating then stop the process and return w,b

    return w,b, train_loss, test_loss



alpha=0.0001
eta0=0.0001
N=len(X_train)
epochs=50
w,b, train_loss, test_loss=train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0)
```

Thew, b results in

```
(array([-0.22281323,  0.10570237, -0.02506523,  0.16630429, -0.07033019,
         0.27985805, -0.27348925, -0.04622113,  0.13212066,  0.05330409,
         0.09926212, -0.00791336, -0.02920803,  0.1828124 ,  0.03442375]),
 -0.8019981458384148)
```

Please Help.

Comment: Look like AAIC's assignment

Answer (score 1):

In your function `gradient_dw ()` the `alpha` (i.e. the regularization term) should be in the numerator.

```py
def gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
    '''In this function, we will compute the gardient w.r.to w '''
    z = np.dot(w, x) + b
    dw = x*(y - sigmoid(z)) - ((alpha)*(1/N) * w)
    return dw
```

As the cost function of the logistic regression with regularization, is

[image: Imgur]

And the gradient descent algorithm becomes following, by taking derivatives of the cost function w.r.t. weights

[image: Imgur]

Another small correction to your code - need to add the **intercept** `b` for calculation of the predicted values array to the following lines

```py
y_pred = [sigmoid(np.dot(w, x) + b) for x in X_train]
y_pred_test = [sigmoid(np.dot(w, x) + b) for x in X_test]
```

---

So in the final form of the full code is as below and it would give the difference with the Scikit-learn implementation in the order of 0.001 for all the weights.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=50000, n_features=15, n_informative=10, n_redundant=5,
                           n_classes=2, weights=[0.7], class_sep=0.7, random_state=15)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=15)

clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(eta0=0.0001, alpha=0.0001, loss='log', random_state=15, penalty='l2', tol=1e-3, verbose=2, learning_rate='constant')

clf.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train) # fitting our model

print(clf.coef_, clf.coef_.shape, clf.intercept_)

def initialize_weights(dim):
    ''' In this function, we will initialize our weights and bias'''
    #initialize the weights to zeros array of (dim,1) dimensions
    #you use zeros_like function to initialize zero
    #initialize bias to zero
    w = np.zeros_like(dim)
    b = 0

    return w,b

def sigmoid(z):
    ''' In this function, we will return sigmoid of z'''
    # compute sigmoid(z) and return
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def logloss(y_true,y_pred):
    
    '''In this function, we will compute log loss '''
    loss = 0
    A = list(zip(y_true, y_pred))
    for y, y_score in A:
        loss += (-1/len(A))*(y*np.log10(y_score) + (1-y) * np.log10(1-y_score))
    return loss

def gradient_dw(x,y,w,b,alpha,N):
    '''In this function, we will compute the gardient w.r.to w '''
    z = np.dot(w, x) + b
    dw = x*(y - sigmoid(z)) - ((alpha)*(1/N) * w)
    return dw

def gradient_db(x,y,w,b):
    z = np.dot(w, x) + b
    db = y - sigmoid(z)
    return db

def train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0, tol=1e-3):
    ''' In this function, we will implement logistic regression'''
    #Here eta0 is learning rate
    #implement the code as follows
    # initalize the weights (call the initialize_weights(X_train[0]) function)
    w, b = initialize_weights(X_train[0])
    # for every epoch
    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # for every data point(X_train,y_train)
        for x, y in zip(X_train, y_train):
             #compute gradient w.r.to w (call the gradient_dw() function)
            dw = gradient_dw(x, y, w, b, alpha, len(X_train))
            #compute gradient w.r.to b (call the gradient_db() function)
            db = gradient_db(x, y, w, b)
            #update w, b
            w = w + eta0 * dw
            b = b + eta0 * db
        
        # predict the output of x_train[for all data points in X_train] using w,b
        y_pred = [sigmoid(np.dot(w, x)) for x in X_train]
        #compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)
        train_loss.append(logloss(y_train, y_pred))
        # store all the train loss values in a list
        # predict the output of x_test[for all data points in X_test] using w,b
        y_pred_test = [sigmoid(np.dot(w, x)) for x in X_test]
        print(f"EPOCH: {epoch} Train Loss: {logloss(y_train, y_pred)} Test Loss: {logloss(y_test, y_pred_test)}")
        #compute the loss between predicted and actual values (call the loss function)
        test_loss.append(logloss(y_test, y_pred_test))
        
        # you can also compare previous loss and current loss if the loss is not updating then stop the process and return w,b

    return w,b, train_loss, test_loss

alpha=0.0001
eta0=0.0001
N=len(X_train)
epochs=50
w,b, train_loss, test_loss=train(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,epochs,alpha,eta0)


print("Difference between custom w and Scikit-learn's clf.coef_ ", w - clf.coef_)
print("Difference between custom intercept b and Scikit-learn's clf.intercept_ ", b - clf.intercept_)
```

#### Output as below

```
Difference between custom w and Scikit-learn's clf.coef_  [[-0.00642552  0.00755955  0.00012041 -0.00335043 -0.01309563  0.00978314
   0.00724319  0.00418409  0.0125563  -0.00701162  0.00169655 -0.00480346
  -0.00173041  0.00056208  0.00032075]]
Difference between custom intercept b and Scikit-learn's clf.intercept_  [-0.03911387]
```